# Change Wordpress theme but keep all old articles on old theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I don't know if this is possible but I hope it is.

I run a very large Wordpress site with over 20 000 articles and I need to do a redesign now. However I'm trying to cheat by keeping all the existing articles in the same theme we are in now and only changing the new articles and the front page.

This is because a lot of the articles have custom page themes and embedded features that require the old functions.

So the question is, can I do this. is it even possble?

Or can I create static HTML files for every current article so when someone views it they get the old HTML instead of the new theme.

Also are there any terrible ideas here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try adding a specific category to the old posts, say `archives`, and serving a different theme if the category or a single post in it is being viewed:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Theme for Archived Posts
 */
add_action( 'setup_theme', 'setup_so_23040011' );

function setup_so_23040011() 
{
    add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'switch_so_23040011' );
    add_filter( 'template',   'switch_so_23040011' );
} 

function switch_so_23040011( $value ) 
{
    if( is_category('archives') || in_category('archives') )
        return 'twentytwelve'; // <-- The old theme
    return $value;
}
```

To automate the assignment of the category to all 20k posts, another plugin with an `on_activation` procedure to iterate through them all and add the `archives` category. Something [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71014/12615), but adapted to add the cat. Just activate and let it run, de-activate and delete afterwards (make sure to backup the db beforehand).

Comment: That's brilliant in it's simplicity :).. As for tagging them all in a specific category I think I'd rather do that directly va the mysql admin... would be easier for my skillset